# Does data fetch from data base effects speed of application in iOS development

Tags: ios, iphone, database

I like to know about does it effect, if I fetch data every time from core data base to show it many places or I fetch data once and store it locally and use,  does it effect the speed of app. Please suggest me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,it affects the speed of fetching each time..so it w'll better to fetch it once,store locally & use it.

Comment: it will use free memory of mobile, and what i know free memory good for app speed up, may be i am confuse clear it

Comment: when we store locally means we are storing to app's documents folder or simply we can say in app.so i think it w'll use phone's memory..

Comment: i have 500 records in core data and representing in table view, while i tap any row it will show related information on next view, what should be the best approach for me fetch every time  or fetch records only once

Comment: r u satisfied with my ans..means your confusion is clear or still not??

Comment: if your core data is not updating then you should fetch it once..it w'll be better & w'll speed up..

Comment: ok then surely you have to fetch it once only...& just make some condtion or say flag if on server data is updated then than time you w'll fetch only & d=store locally...:)

Answer (score 1):

Just a point of clarification when you say fetch data every time from core data base do you mean from core data? Assuming you mean the core database:

Fetching data across a network is slow even slower when you factor in mobile network conditions. Your app will perform much faster if you cache this information locally and use core data or cloud data to make sure it invalidates appropriately.

Comment: i have 500 records in core data and representing in table view, while i tap any row it will show related information on next view, what should be the best approach for me fetch every time  or fetch records only once

Comment: From Apple's Docs: Each round trip to the persistent store (each fetch) incurs an overhead, both in accessing the store and in merging the returned objects into the persistence stack. You should avoid executing multiple requests if you can instead combine them into a single request that will return all the objects you require. You can also minimize the number of objects you have in memory.

Comment: thank you very much davidbates, so i go with fetch once option .